# Django Tutorial Part 3 - Template

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. So please excuse if my question is trivial.

This is in reference to Django Docs, [tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs/)

In Section **Decoupling the URLConfs**, the authors says to to have the following in **mysite/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and the below code to be part of **polls/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'vote'),
)
```

I HAVE BEEN WADING THRU THIS TUTORIAL BY HAVING THE URLS.PY IN Polls DIRECTORY.

IS THERE MYSITE DIRECTORY AS WELL AS POLLS DIRECTORY THAT HAS URLS.PY?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: WHY DON'T YOU WADE THROUGH BY HAVING URLS.PY WHERE IT SAYS?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things about django is that it prides itself on its ability to have apps that are pluggable and modular. The `urls.py` inside the `mysite` directory is your PROJECT wide url conf.

This line

`url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),`

tells your PROJECT that you have an app/directory/python package that has a `urls.py` file. In this file which lives in `mysite/polls/urls.py` you will have the url conf for the polls APPLICATION that will live at `/polls/whatever` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks a mil for the very quick response. But I still don't get it. My directory is as follows: <br> <Django_Dir>/Polls - This directory has manage.py (file), templates(directory) and polls (directory)<br> . And Polls Directory contains __init__.py, urls.py, settinsg.py etc. In order to decouple, which are the 2 directories where in the respective urls.py should belong? (sorry my previous question had not been completed)

Comment: Ok what don't you get? I tried to cover the concepts broadly because your post wasn't very specific.

Comment: Thanks a mil for the very quick response. But I still don't get it. My directory is as follows:
 <Django_Dir>/Polls - This directory has manage.py (file), templates(directory) and  . 
 <Django_Dir>/Polls/Polls Directory . This contains init.py, urls.py, settinsg.py etc.

In order to decouple, which are the 2 directories where in the respective urls.py should belong? (sorry my previous question had not been completed. I am new to Stackoverflow as well (:

Comment: All the information is at [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/). I forgot about the new directory structure 1.4 has.

The way it works now is you have a `mysite` with only a `manage.py` and another `mysite` with `__init__.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`, and `wsgi.py`. Then when  you create another app you will put it next to the `manage.py`.

Comment: I know you are new to Stack Overflow but if you found my answer/help useful please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in python. Coincidentally I just went through the entire tutorial by chance a few hours ago. Your `urls.py` should only be located in `/mysite/mysite/` directory.

This is where my `urls.py` is located

> /home/mattrising/desktop/mysite/mysite#

Hope that helps :-)

Edit: your `polls` directory should NOT contain `urls.py` file by default.

Comment: You are correct that `urls.py` will not be in the app by default but it is good to separate urls per app. This way if you want to move the app from one site/project to another all you have to do is add one line to the site/projects url conf that includes the `polls` app urls.